# Why Atom Separate all the tabs on reopening?

Tags: macos, atom-editor

I open atom with at lease 7 different tabs, that's what I like it with the atom that on the same window you can open multiple projects in a different tab.

But the pain is when I restart my mac. Atom every time open all the projects(different tabs) in seprate windows. So there will be like 7 different windows every time. And unfortunately, I can not able to combine them all in one Window. So I have to close other 6 tabs for an example and then keep reopening again for combining them.

So the question is, **Is there any way that I can reopen atom from my last session, like exactly same it was?**

Using Atom 1.18.0

Comment: Have you looked at the settings? In section Core, there is a setting "Restore Previous Windows on Start" - I believe if you set that to "always" it might do what you are looking for.

Comment: Yeah, I already checked that. In my case, it's a checkbox and I marked as True. Atom does restore previous windows on start but here my problem is, (for an example) I open 10 different projects in 10 different tabs but in a single window and when atom restored it, those all projects open in different separate windows. And I want to open that 10 projects in one single window.

Thanks for your reposnse though @DanLowe.

Comment: Are you on the latest Atom? They changed that setting in 1.17 or 1.18, it is now a 3-option pulldown and it behaves differently than it used to.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up. I was using Atom 1.15. I just replaced it with 1.18 latest stable release. It's strange that every time I check for update Atom didn't suggest me that there is a new version. It was just checking for packages that I installed. Anyways today I am trying the new version. I will update with status. Thanks for your help @DanLowe

Comment: I found that until recently Atom's updater was a little bit flaky... but it seems to be working properly the last couple of major releases. For me, at least.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to do a manual update. 
Back to the problem, so if you open multiple projects in different tabs but in the same window. And do cmd + q (I think which is equivalent when you do restart mac os). And see Atom will open all that projects in a different window and somehow you could combine them. You have to close other except one and reopen all. (Tried in Atom 1.18, having the same issue) @DanLowe

Comment: there is no restore previous session check box